Emacs gets stuck in installing packages in Windows
I`m trying to install emacs and spacemacs for the first time in my life in Windows. So I followed the roadmap for installing that from this link. But when I open emacs, I see this picture, and it gets stuck for installing packages forever.


Just do an installation without any packages first. Once you have emacs installed and running, you can debug the package situation separately.
